# php display error before form submission

Tags: php, html, submit

i have a simple php script:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>MY WEB</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="textval" value="<?php if( isset($_GET['textval']) ) echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['textval']) ?>" />
        <input type="submit" value="Check" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
if ( empty($_GET['textval']) ) {
    echo "Please Fill The TextBox" . PHP_EOL;  // displays this
}
else{
    echo "OKAY" . PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

But php throws this error just after opening the page and i didn't submitted the form !!!

how to solve this ?

Comment: *throws this error* what error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you edited your code, obviously it will show that statement as `if` condition will return `true`, so in this case, assign a `name` to your `submit` button, and than use like

```
<input type="submit" value="Check" name="submitted" />

<?php
if(isset($_GET['submitted'])) {
   if (empty($_GET['textval'])) {
       echo "Please Fill The TextBox" . PHP_EOL;  // displays this
   }
   else{
       echo "OKAY" . PHP_EOL;
   }
}
?>
```

> Note: It is better if you use `POST` instead of `GET` as this doesn't
>   seem like `$_GET` suitable thing, generally `$_GET` is used for search
>   pages.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>MY WEB</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="textval" value="<?php if( isset($_GET['textval']) ) echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['textval']) ?>" />
        <input type="submit" value="Check" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['submitted'])){
  if ( empty($_GET['textval']) ) {
    echo "Please Fill The TextBox" . PHP_EOL;
  }
  else{
    echo "OKAY" . PHP_EOL;
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Oops, you copy pasted my code but forgot to assign a `name` to the submit button :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `$_GET['textval']` is initially empty, so `empty($_GET['textval'])` condition is `true`.

That is why you have error on the first page load.

Comment: but how to stop this ?

Comment: use condition first if($_GET) {  if (empty($_GET['textval'])) { } } like this

Answer (score 0):

according to your code

```
empty($_GET['textval'])
```

will always give TRUE before form submission. So first check if your form was submitted or not.

first change submit to

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Check" />
```

now check if submit is valid or not

```
 if(isset($_GET['textval'])) {
     if(isset($_POST['submitted'])){
         if ( empty($_GET['textval']) ) {
               echo "Please Fill The TextBox" . PHP_EOL;
         }
         else{
               echo "OKAY" . PHP_EOL;
         }
     } 
    }
```

or for your code add a hidden input with name 'submitted' and check for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use JQuery to validate if fields are empty. This will not reload the page.

```
$("form").submit(function (e){
    if($("input[type='text']").val().length == 0)
    {
       alert('fill form');
       return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: yes i tried to do this but i have to echo the error on html page not to alert it. but the jquery code should not allow the form to submit

Comment: then use $().text function instead alert :)